# How to apply limit and startAt to child items of firestore document

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to apply pagination in firestore, i need to take the first 5 items of (200 total items) from the **items** array in my **hats** doc from **collections** collection, and then on next click i need to get he next 5 and so on.

```
testPagination = async () => {

    const { currentPage, itemsPerPage } = this.state;
    const { fetchCollectionsForPagesStart, match : { params } } = this.props;
    const collectionId = params.collectionId;

    const startAt = currentPage * itemsPerPage - itemsPerPage;

    const docs =  await firestore.collection("collections").orderBy('id').startAt(0).limit(itemsPerPage).get();
    const data = docs.docs;

    const items = docs.forEach( async docItem => {
        console.log(await docItem.data());
    })
}
```

i run this function when i click a button in my render function inside react,

```
render()
{
    return (
        <button onClick={this.testPagination}>Test pagination </button>
    );
}
```

but i am always getting 200 items in my result, so how do i apply startAt() and limit() to items array in firestore.

This is my db :

[image]

This console.log(await docItem.data()); gives me

[image]

NB : I'm receiving the hats document id, so if there is a way to access hats with id in would want some help in that too i have tried

```
const docs = await firestore.doc(`collections/${collectionId}`).get();
const data = await docs.data();
```

But this doesn't allow me to apply startAt() and limit()

Comment: Surely this will not fix your issue, but `currentPage` and `startAt` are constants and they need to be variables. Inside `startAt()` method you're sending currentPage instead of startAt.

Comment: Not the answer to your problem, but the `await` in here is meaningless: `console.log(await docItem.data());`. Same for this one `const data = await docs.data();`. Calling `get()` is an asynchronous operation that returns a promise, but calling `data` on the document is not asynchronous.

Comment: We have no idea to know what value `currentPage`, which makes it hard to say what's going wrong. Please edit your question to include the [minimal, complete/standalone code that any of us can run to reproduce the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I highly recommend studying that link, as (for example) I doubt you need to use ReactJS to reproduce the problem. The less code is needed and the more standalone that code is, the more likely it is that one of us can reproduce the problem, and spot what's going wrong for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your database, `hats` is a document of `collections` collection. In Firestore you can't bring a part of a document (5 items from your `items` array, for example) always brings all the document and it counts as one read in Firestore.
If you want to make pagination on `items` array you must create a subcollection in `hats` with the data on `items`. Having this structure you can perform a `startAtQuery()` with a `limit()` of 5 documents, which in this case it counts as 5 reads in Firestore.

You can see all about the Firestore data model here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/data-model

Comment: How do i create subcollection on hats ? can you please explain?

Comment: It's like creating a normal collection. In Firestore, go to collections > hats > + Start collection. There you can create a subcollection. Inside this new subcollection, you can create documents, in your case you can create documents with data from your items array.

Comment: You can see information about subcollections and all about the Firestore data model here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/data-model